# PHP - html_entity_decode not decoding everything

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am parsing an HTML page. At some point I am getting the text between a div and using 
html_entity_decode to print that text.

The problem is that the page contains characters like this star `★` or others like shapes like ⬛︎, ◄, ◉, etc. I have checked and these characters are not encoded on the source page, they are like you see them normally.

The page is using charset="UTF-8"

So, when I use

```
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

The star, for example, is "decoded" to  `â˜`

$string is being obtained by using

```
document.getElementById("id-of-div").innerText
```

I would like to decode them correctly. How do I do that in PHP?

NOTE: I have tried `htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);` and it produces the same result.

Comment: 1. Does the star have an equivalent HTML entity? 2. So, what does `$string` contain? 3. It seems like a character code issue to me.

Comment: 1. I don't have a clue. 2. in theory all the string contained in a specific div. 3. I am not sure.

Comment: Re 2: but which entity is decoded to `â˜`?

Comment: "I have checked and these characters are not encoded on the source page ... I would like to decode them correctly." If they're not encoded, how exactly do you expect to decode them? `html_entity_decode` is purely about converting entities of the form `&something;` (including numeric values of `something`) to "real" characters. What you have here looks like a UTF-8 string which you're then echoing in a non-UTF-8 context.

Comment: Indeed. Part of the question is really, *why* are you trying to do this? If you've got some UTF-8 characters you want to print out, why are you doing html_entity_decode at all? Why not just, er, print them out? And can we see an example of the source document and your actual code?

Comment: I've just tested html_entity_decode on the characters in your question, and, as expected, it leaves them untouched. How are you creating your output, and how are you looking at it? My guess: html_entity_decode is a red herring, and you're actually outputting untouched UTF-8 characters, but your character encoding is wrong, so they get mangled on display.

Comment: this is what I thought, but for some reason these characters are being processed.

Comment: No, I honestly don't think they are.

Comment: I am obtaining the string inside the div by using something like `document.getElementById("id-of-div").innerText`... I think this is forcing the chars to be transformed... what command should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue with this simple bit of PHP:

```
<?php
  // Make sure our client knows we're sending UTF-8
  header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
  $string = "The page contains characters like this star ★ or others like shapes like ⬛︎, ◄, ◉, etc. Here are some entities: This is a &quot;test&quot;.";
  echo 'String: ' . $string . "\n";
  echo 'Decoded: ' . html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

As expected, the output is:

```
String: The page contains characters like this star ★ or others like shapes like ⬛︎, ◄, ◉, etc. Here are some entities: This is a &quot;test&quot;.
Decoded: The page contains characters like this star ★ or others like shapes like ⬛︎, ◄, ◉, etc. Here are some entities: This is a "test".
```

If I change the charset in the header to `iso-8859-1`, I see this:

```
String: The page contains characters like this star â˜… or others like shapes like â¬›ï¸Ž, â—„, â—‰, etc. Here are some entities: <span>This is a &quot;test&quot;.
Decoded: The page contains characters like this star â˜… or others like shapes like â¬›ï¸Ž, â—„, â—‰, etc. Here are some entities: <span>This is a "test".
```

So, I'd say that your issue is a display issue. The "interesting" characters are being left completely untouched by `html_entity_decode`, as you'd expect. It's just that whatever code you've got, or whatever you're using to look at your output, is using incorrectly using iso-8859-1 to display them.

Comment: you are right! T H A N K S! I forgot to add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to the beginning of the code, so it would force UTF-8 to the output. Thanks!